# Django Related Object empty queryset on clean()

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying access a list of related objects through the "related_set.all()" method whenever a model is saved from Django Admin. No matter what I do however the QuerySet is always empty... Here's what it looks like (I've removed a lot of (hopefully) irrelevant stuff)

```
class Board(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def clean(self):
        roles = self.role_set.all() # This just returns <QuerySet []> 

        ... validation, etc....   

class Role(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Funny thing is that it used to work, but after setting the User to be the AUTH_USER_MODEL (after a lot of refactoring) it suddenly stopped returning anything in the QuerySet... For what it matters I'm using a NestedStackedInline in the Admin panel, and what I hope to achieve is that whenever the "Save"-button in the admin panel is called, it should call the clean() method on the Role-class, call the clean() method on the Board-class and upon success call the save() method on both.

I've been troubleshooting this for way too long now and would really appreciate if anyone have some pointers or ideas.

Comment: Hi, is it ok to see what you have set `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to in your `settings.py` file please

Comment: I'm positive that the AUTH_USER_MODEL points to the correct User, as I've also tried pointing members directly to the User-model without any luck.

Comment: Is it possible to include that line ... I'll be able to rule that out then...

Comment: Sure: 
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = "database.UserModel"

Comment: And to be pedantic what is your `User` class called in your `models.py` file, and does it contain the correct references to `Group`? And is your app called `database`? Otherwise, it is likely to be wrong...

Comment: Ye, all of the above. The error seems to lie somewhere between the Board- and the Role-models. There might also be an error with the NestedStackInline, however this seems unlikely from my debugging...

Comment: Very difficult to tell what your issue is, are you able to strip your project back to the point and which it was working...?

Comment: Sadly no, not while retaining the changes, so I'll continue troubleshooting the problem at hand

Comment: Yes - feel free tomorrow to send over your code and I will see if I can help debug for you.

Comment: Appreciate it! Ill see how I fare